# how I print lines for the same id

Tags: php

i am with one little difficulty to doesone print here for example: 
one table with sells and other with with sells details

table sells

```
id_sell | name | price
------- + ---- + -----
1       | jonh | 300$ 
------- + ---- + -----
2       | carl | 500$ 
------- + ---- + -----
3       | mike | 50$
```

table sale details

```
id_detail | id_sell | product 
--------- + ------- + ----------
1         | 1       | car
--------- + ------- + ----------
2         | 1       | car2
--------- + ------- + ----------
3         | 1       | car3
--------- + ------- + ----------
4         | 2       | bike
--------- + ------- + ----------
5         | 2       | motor bike
--------- + ------- + ----------
6         | 3       | plane
```

output:

'name' buy 'product' and pay 'price'

'jonh' buy 'car'

jonh buy car2

jonh buy car3

carl buy bike

carl buy motor bike

mike buy plane

In other words, I have the table of sells and sale details and I wanted that while sales of jonh are required, jonh is printed and so it is repeated

---

old: ///

sell contain:
sell id: 1
name: jonh
state: pending
price: 100$

sell id: 2
name: jonathan
state: pending
price: 200$

and the sell detais contain:

sell id: 1
produt: car1
obs: xxxxx
date: 11/11/2020

sell id: 1
produt: car2
obs: xxxxx
date: 11/11/2020

sell id: 1
produt: car3
obs: xxxxx
date: 11/11/2020

sell id: 2
produt: bike
obs: qqqqq
date: 1/1/2020
sell id: 2

produt: bike2
obs: qqqqq
date: 1/1/2020

How can I print the same sales table data as the detailed sales table as long as there are detailed sales table lines with the same sales id?

```
if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Nº </th>";
        echo "<th>Client</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>
        echo "<th>Câmbio</th>";
        echo "<th>Artigo</th>";
        echo "<th>Quantidade</th>";
        echo "<th>Preço</th>";
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<p> </p>";
        while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
            echo "";
            echo "<td>" . $row['venda_id'] . ";";
            echo "" . $row['cliente_id'] . ";";
            echo "" . $row['data_inicio'] . ";";
            echo "EUR</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        unset($res);
    } else {
        echo "No existe nothing";
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna do.

Comment: the goal was to fetch the sales id and print the rows from another table while existing with the same id

Comment: Please re-word your question and provide an example of how you would like the output to look like. Currently it is so difficult to tell what you are aiming for.

Comment: more explicit now? and I try ..

Comment: I still can't understand, but I will edit your question hoping that someone else can read it and amswer.

Comment: found out, I got it using INNER JOIN thanks anyway